# A question on continuity of a piecewise function with 4 constants

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I have this function, and I need to find the values of $a, b, c$ and $d$ so that $f(x)$ will be differentiable everywhere.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
ax+b, & x<-2 \\
x^2+c, & -2\le x\le2\\
{d\over x}+3, & x>2
\end{cases}$$

I've done these kinds of problems before, but this is the first one I've encountered where one of the pieces has a variable *and* a constant ($x^2+c$). I've tried setting limits on either side of $-2$ and $2$ to be equal, like this:
$$\lim_{x\to -2^-} ax+b=\lim_{x\to -2^+} x^2+c$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-} x^2+c=\lim_{x\to 2^+} {d\over x}+3$$
but this hasn't led me anywhere.

How do I start this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to make the function continuous or differentiable?

Comment: To be differentiable everywhere doesn't it need to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, but it also gives you extra information. For example, You know that a = -4. Why?

Comment: I'm didn't know that a=-4, I haven't been able to figure out a single numerical value for any of the constants.

Comment: The derivative of $ax + b$ at -2 has to equal the derivative of $x^2 + c$ at -2. Can you see how to get the rest?

Comment: Oh! So after deriving I should get $a=2x$, which I then multiply by -2, right?

Comment: Yes, and that gives you your third equation. Setting the derivative of $x^2+c$ equal to the derivative of $\frac{d}{x} + 3$ at x = 2 gives you your fourth. You now have 4 equations and 4 unknowns.

Comment: Perfect, I know what to do now. Thank you!